# Firebase Storage Download Url Error: Invalid HTTP method/URL pair

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a file on Firebase Storage and store that download url in Firebase Firestore.

This is my upload code:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var metadata = {
    contentType: "application/vnd.ms-pki.stl"
};
var uploadTask = storageRef
    .child(`users/${user.uid}/tmp/` + filename)
    .put(file, metadata);

uploadTask.on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, 
    function () {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
            db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('tmp').add({
                    product_id: filename,
                    downloadurl: downloadURL,
                    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
        });
    }
```

When I try to download the file using the download url in my browser I get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
 }
}
```